# Set Wallpaper when images are from arraylist

Tags: android, arrays, wallpaper

How could i set wallpaper when the images are stored in arraylist i have tried but no hope!!

here is the code:

```
final ImageView image = new ImageView(mContext);
image.setImageResource(mImageIds[pos]);                 

try {
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(image.getDrawingCache());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried using above code but it showing `NullPointer Exception`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could've showed a bit more code (how is your array, string name of picture or int id). anyway ill show you how i did similiar thing:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
    final int[] imgs = new int[] { R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3,
            R.drawable.i4, R.drawable.i5, R.drawable.i6, R.drawable.i7,
            R.drawable.i8, R.drawable.i9, R.drawable.i10, };

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                    imgs[pos]);         
            try {
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: dont mention it, glad I could help!

Comment: Marko Niciforovic  i have one more doubt .how could we select each item from list dialog box

Comment: its hard to tell without seeing your code, maybe this link here can help, it shows listview in dialog box and how to get selected item http://cssinnovations.blogspot.com/2012/07/selection-list-in-alert-dialog-box.html

Comment: Marko Niciforovic  Thanks..i will check